# Should I use BackgroundWorker in Pipeline pattern?

Tags: c#, concurrency, wpf

I am planning the implementation of a Pipeline pattern as seen [in this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx). This is a WPF application for which I need to monitor progress of each stage of the pipeline in order to display it in the GUI.

Is it okay to implement each stage of a Pipeline with a BackgroundWorker? If not then why and what is/are the correct class/classes to use in order to support the pipeline pattern and also report progress to the GUI.

Comment: Just implement the pipeline on its own thread(s), and call Invoke() to post the progress to the GUI.  If you want decoupling from the GUI, you can use an Observer pattern.

Comment: The reactive extensions library makes for a nice implementation of the observer pattern, start looking around at http://reactivex.io/

Answer (score 2):

The article you linked to is using `Task`s, you should should do that too, instead of `BackgroundWorkder`. There are many reasons why `Task`s are preferable, Stephen Cleary has a [series of articles](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html) explaining why.